# Nested static constexpr of incomplete type. Valid C++ or not?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-members, constexpr

Clang and GCC disagree on whether the following code is valid `C++11` or not:

```
struct Thing {
    int value;
    static const Thing thing;
};

constexpr Thing Thing::thing {3};
```

Clang compiles it and `GNU GCC version 4.7.2` says:
`error: redeclaration ‘Thing::thing’ differs in ‘constexpr’
constexpr Thing Thing::thing {3};`

Which compiler's interpretation of the standard is correct? And does it seem like the `C++14` standard is going to have something new to say relating to this matter?

Comment: Same appears to be true with GCC 4.8.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Introduction

The snippet is legal *C++11*, and there is no change in *C++14*.

> <sup>**Note**: *`gcc 4.9.0`* correctly accepts the snippet, ie. rejecting the snippet was a bug in previous versions of the compiler.</sup>

---

#### Explanation

The *constexpr* specifier certainly affects the object being defined (it will be declared *const*), but in particular the specifier mandates that the object declared;

- is a *literal type*, and;
- has an initializer, and;
- that the initializer is a *constant expression*.

```
struct Thing {
  int value;
  static const Thing thing;       // (A)
};

constexpr Thing Thing::thing {3}; // (B)
```

This means that the definition (B) refers to an object of type `Thing const` named *thing*, which is the same as (A), hence; the snippet is legal.

> `7.1.5p9` **The `constexpr` specifier** `[dcl.constexpr]` ([**n3337**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))
>
> > A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const.` Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized.